# Solving underdetermined nonlinear system of 2 equation with 3 unknowns.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis

I've gotten into a problem I haven't really worked with before in my numerics classes.

I have an underdetermined nonlinear system of equations with 3 real-valued parameters, precisely those parameters are angles $\in$ $[0,\pi/2]$.
The system is defined as:

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
A=\cos(\alpha)e^{i\phi}\\
B=\sin(\alpha)e^{i\chi}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
 where $A$ and $B$ are two known complex-valued  parameters.

Newtons method, Boydens method etc. all include the inverse of the jacobian, but if the system is underdetermined this is not defined as far as I understand 
Is there any straightforward way or trick to solve this kind of problems?

Comment: Are $\alpha, \phi, \chi$ real-valued?

Comment: Are $\phi$,$\alpha$ and $\chi$ complex- or real-valued?

Comment: $\alpha$, $\phi$,  and $\chi$ are real-valued (angles in specific boundaries)